# Javascript for loop to get unique failed

Tags: javascript

I'm figuring out how to find the unique content that's in `var test`.
In `var test` there's 5 content with the first row as `contentId`.
So, I have a `var contentId` to show number of used contentId used from `var test`. So I'm pushing every content `test` into an array , and looping to find which contentid is not being used.

```js
var test = "1#2#Did You Know?#Digital is rapid! A pair of BioCarbon Engineering drones can plant almost 100 ,000 trees a day.#8#Yes\n2#2#Did You Know?#Starting this summer of 2017, Ikea's smart light bulbs will answer voice commands given to Amazon Alexa, Google Assistant, or Apple Siri. The Internet of Things (IoT) is revolutionising everyday appliances!#5#Unknown\n3#2#Did You Know?#Cemex's (a cement company) collaboration platform allows employees to share opinions, knowledge, and best practices. The ideas from every corner of Cemex have led to new initiatives and business outcomes.#5#Unknown\n4#2#Did You Know?#Cemex's (a cement company) collaboration platform allows employees to share opinions, knowledge, and best practices. The ideas from every corner of Cemex have led to new initiatives and business outcomes.#5#Unknown\n5#3#Did You Know?#Cemex's (a cement company) collaboration platform allows employees to share opinions, knowledge, and best practices. The ideas from every corner of Cemex have led to new initiatives and business outcomes.#5#Unknown\n";

//console.log(test);
var result = [];
var allRows = test.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
var week = '2';
var contentid = '3,2,1';
var splitContentId = contentid.split(/,/);
var counterLoop = splitContentId.length;
for (var singleRow = 0; singleRow < allRows.length; singleRow++) {
    var rowCells = allRows[singleRow].split('#');

    for (var zeus = 0; zeus < counterLoop; zeus++) {

        if (rowCells[0] == splitContentId[zeus] && rowCells[1] == week) {
            console.log(rowCells[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

TLDR ;
Finding unique id that's not being used in `var test` . The used contentid is `var contentid`

JSFiddle :-
https://jsfiddle.net/gyp3awja/

Comment: your question is not clear, what is the expected output above?

Comment: @Dij, to return contentId 4 and 5.

Comment: can you elaborate more? why 4 and 5?

Comment: @Dij, I have 5 contents, in a text file. So the identifier is the first column. So i value of the user used id , contentid `3,2,1` . So i'm trying to exclude these contentid and get the remaining other 2 contentid from the text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to see if it match your expectation:

```
var test = "1#2#Did You Know?#Digital is rapid! A pair of BioCarbon Engineering drones can plant almost 100 ,000 trees a day.#8#Yes\n2#2#Did You Know?#Starting this summer of 2017, Ikea's smart light bulbs will answer voice commands given to Amazon Alexa, Google Assistant, or Apple Siri. The Internet of Things (IoT) is revolutionising everyday appliances!#5#Unknown\n3#2#Did You Know?#Cemex's (a cement company) collaboration platform allows employees to share opinions, knowledge, and best practices. The ideas from every corner of Cemex have led to new initiatives and business outcomes.#5#Unknown\n4#2#Did You Know?#Cemex's (a cement company) collaboration platform allows employees to share opinions, knowledge, and best practices. The ideas from every corner of Cemex have led to new initiatives and business outcomes.#5#Unknown\n5#3#Did You Know?#Cemex's (a cement company) collaboration platform allows employees to share opinions, knowledge, and best practices. The ideas from every corner of Cemex have led to new initiatives and business outcomes.#5#Unknown\n";

var allRows = test.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
var week = '2';
var contentid = '3,2,1';
var splitContentId = contentid.split(/,/);
allRows.forEach(function(row) {
    var rowData = row.split('#');
    var rowId = rowData[0];
    var rowWeek = rowData[1];

    if (splitContentId.indexOf(rowId) < 0 || rowWeek != week) {
        console.log(rowId);
    }
})
```

Updated solution

Comment: Not sure why it's not working when i paste it, lemme read it.

Comment: i've added my jsfiddle

Comment: Hi, i've just uppdated the solution.

Comment: you , my friend. Literally gave me new knowledge about map today .